# how to animate(transition) view from left to right?

Tags: android, android-layout

how to animate(transition) view from  left to right.and hide and show on touch event.

thankx

Comment: What do you mean by "hide and show on touch event"?

Comment: Do you want this transition to occur when you change from one activity to the other or within the same activity?? Can you give specifics of what you actually want?

Comment: if it is the same view what we have to do to see the animation.